# Why does the url property key in Firebase snapshot keep changing?

Tags: firebase

I have not seen any discussion or awareness so far that Firebase does in fact make available a unique identifier--in fact the full URL--to each specific data record via their "snapshot" which they return, i.e. the wrapper around the data record (accessed via snapshot.val()). By doing a basic property examination of the snapshot I discovered that the unique URL is available (see examples below). However, it seems that, for some reason, Firebase keeps changing the name of the key every few days, causing my application to break. I have to go in and re-discover the new URL property key and change it so that it will work again.

Here are three examples of how I have seen the key change so far. Each value is the same, but the key keeps changing over time (i.e.: "Wb", "Xb", "bc").:

```
getMemberBySnapshot - snapshot has prop Wb with value https://prototype1.firebaseio.com/users/-IwohKfw1l5F3gFqyJJ5

getMemberBySnapshot - snapshot has prop Xb with value https://prototype1.firebaseio.com/users/-IwohKfw1l5F3gFqyJJ5

getMemberBySnapshot - snapshot has prop bc with value https://prototype1.firebaseio.com/users/-IwohKfw1l5F3gFqyJJ5
```

I have read Firebase's suggestions that developers should use an email address if they want a unique key (what if my model does not use an email field? What if a user wants to change their email?), or Firebase suggests altenatively to retrieve all existing records and then search through them on the client. Neither of these solutions are satisfying. But I'm seeing that they do provide the unique URL to each data record in the 'snapshot'. Why do they not provide a stabilized key so that a developer can call it consistently???

Answer (score 2):

Firebase.js is a compiled script.  The names of internal variables will change every time we compile it and release a new version, so you should definitely not be relying on any properties that are not documented on our website.

For your specific case, you should be using:

```
snapshot.ref().toString()
```

in order to get the URL.

Comment: thank you for your rapid response! Just as a suggestion, I would say that the documentation could be clearer. What you have provided me is clear: to obtain the URL for the data record from a 'snapshot' I just code snapshot.ref().toString(). But the Firebase documentation makes it seem that ref() is something that the Firebase user creates: >>>Usage
var ref = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/users');
var query = ref.limit(5);
var refToSameLocation = query.ref();<<<

Comment: Further clarification: I create my records by push() or set(), not by setting a URL, but the documentation example seems to be tied to the user setting the URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll see what we can do. :-)